# Show the sum of a value entered into an EditText plus a constant

Tags: java, android

For example (1+2 = 3) but I am getting (1+2=12).

Here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final EditText ed=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    final EditText ed1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    ed.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {




        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {

            ed1.setText(ed.getText().toString()+2);
        }

    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to

```
  ed1.setText(Integer.parseInt(ed.getText().toString())+2);
```

instead of

```
  ed1.setText(ed.getText().toString()+2);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a String. A String + another String = StringString.
E.g "hello" + "you" = "helloyou";

So parse your String to Integer and start calculating.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to concate two strings , so output is combined. While doing any `arithmetic operation`, parse string to integer and then add them.

```
   int result=Integer.parseInt(ed.getText().toString())+2);
   ed1.setText(String.valueOf(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

ed1.setText(Integer.parseInt(ed.getText().toString())+2);

Answer (score 0):

If you use the operator "+" between a string and an integer, the integer will be converted to string and it will be attached to the string's end.

Let's see an example of what are your doing now:

```
String a = "1";
int b = 2;

System.out.println(a+b);
```

console output: `12`

and what you should do:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;

System.out.println(a+b);
```

console output: `3`

The easiest way to solve this problem is to change your code like this:

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    ed1.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(ed.getText().toString) + 2));

}
```

Note: parsing an unchecked string is quite risky, it can throws exception if the string parsed is not an int and for this reason you should be careful. You may want to set the attribute `android:inputType="numberSigned"` on the xml of your `EditText`. This will force the user to insert only int number in the `EditText`.
Like this:

```
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:inputType="numberSigned" 
    ... />
```